# how to get a specific value from a sentence using regular expression in php

Tags: php, regex, expression

string is given as

```
--------b&gt;Deal Price: $11.04&lt;/b&gt;&l-----------
```

and I want to extract $11.04 from this string. please help me to solve this
using PHP regular expression.

Comment: What you have done so far to achieve this?

Comment: Actually i am creating apis for amazon daily deal. Butt i am wek in Regular expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:, assuming the source string actually contains `<b>`:

```
<?php

$s = '--------<b>Deal Price: $11.04</b>&l-----------';
$m = array();

if (preg_match('#<b>(Deal Price:)\s+(.+)</b>#', $s, $m) == 1) {   
    if (count($m) > 2) {
        echo $m[2];
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks this also work. Thanks again 

Comment: Can you please mark the answer as correct so others can benefit?

Answer (score 0):

You could look for the `$`, followed by digits as in

```
(?<=\$)\d+(?:\.\d+)?
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/PKLJMU/1/).

---

Broken down this says

```
(?<=\$)    # look for $ immediately behind
\d+        # at least one digit, possibly more
(?:        # followed by a non-capturing group
    \.\d+  # a dot and more digits
)?         # but made optional
```

One could argue that Amazon might have prizes like `$10,000` which would not be covered by this expression. Herefore, you could use

```
(?<=\$)\d+[\d,]*(?:\.\d+)?
```

Comment: Thanks man its work. Actually i am wek in regular expression. When i see regular expression my face expression change. It scare to me

Comment: Thanks for help brother 